# What was the Denominational make-up of the Jesus Revolution revival? And is it the same today?

Tags: youth, revival, jesus-movement

Which Christian denomination did it spring from, if any? Or was it a spontaneous rising from the youth culture, meeting a need of sorts?

Perhaps in answering this, it would help to know which denominations "assimilated" them the most? (Evangelical denominations, charismatic churches, modernist main-line churches). If the movement was independent, spontaneous, which denominations reached out to them to help them assimilate?

Do many of them remain independent of all main-line or evangelical churches? Or are most Jesus People assimilated into denominations, and no longer an identifiable Christian sub-group?

P.S. For those who did not live during those times: The Jesus People Revolution was a movement of, originally, hippies, then many other young people, who became turned off by the pagan lifestyle rampant in youth culture in the 70s...and who saw hope, meaning, and joy, in the Gospel message of Jesus Christ.  Many were delivered from drug addiction, immorality, and a rebellious attitude...and returned to productive lives in their families, and neighborhoods.

The movement was so large and influential that the face of Jesus made it to the cover of TIME magazine!  Because of the hippie-style of living, it was hard for some denominations to assimilate them back into church life, though.

Comment: What is "the Jesus Revolution revival"?

Comment: @guest37-The following Answers deal with your curiosity, quite well. But briefly, this was a spiritual revival that occurred in the Providence of God among young people who were in the modern cultural scene of sex, drugs, and rebellion against "whatever."  Many lives were redeemed from sin, released from bondage, freed from drug addiction...and restored to their parents.  It was so influential that the face of Jesus made it to the cover of Time magazine!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I have never been involved in the “Jesus Movement” I found a Christian article that describes how it started in the late 1960’s during a time of protest, uncertainty, and rebellion against societal norms.  Although I was too young to participate in this counter-culture, I was aware of it.

Initially, it seems that in the pursuit of pleasure (which involved psychedelic drugs and sexual “liberation”) many young people of that generation became involved in New Age beliefs and Eastern mysticism.  Part of the article [1] says this:

> In their pursuit of happiness and a cultural utopia, many of these young people came to faith in Jesus Christ, giving birth to the Jesus Movement, also known as the “Jesus revolution” and the “Jesus People Movement.” Because so many of these converts had been drug addicts and street people, they were often called “Jesus freaks.” But not all who joined the Jesus Movement were former drug users and hippies. Many young people left conventional Christian churches in search of more fulfilling spiritual experiences amid the excitement and transformation of this new movement of Christian renewal.

> At the height of the Jesus Movement, adherents were estimated to number anywhere between 30,000 to 3 million people. Many of the early founders of the movement—Ted Wise, Lonnie Frisbee, Chuck Smith, Larry Norman—came from Southern California. Other prominent groups sprang up in Seattle under Linda Meissner (the Jesus People Army) and in Milwaukee headed by Jim and Sue Palosaari (the Jesus People). An offshoot of the Milwaukee movement later grew into the Jesus People USA, which eventually settled in Chicago. This group is one of only a few remaining Christian communes with roots in the original 1970s Jesus Movement.

> Eventually, by the late 1980s, the Jesus Movement disintegrated in two directions. One portion became increasingly cultic and alienated from both the Christian community and the larger society. The other segment was absorbed or reabsorbed into Christian groups such as the Calvary Chapel Association, the Vineyard Movement, Jews for Jesus, and the Christian World Liberation Front.

> Like most revival movements, the Jesus Movement was relatively short-lived but left its mark on Christian history, rejuvenating a portion of the body of Christ through its music, informal worship style, and appeal to young people.

Chuck Smith was one of the Jesus Movement’s principal founders [2].  Here is a partial quote from an article about Chuck Smith and the Calvary Chapel:

> Present-day Calvary Chapels are known for their vibrant worship and chapter-by-chapter, book-by-book Bible teaching. From the start, Smith taught through the whole Bible from beginning to end, a signature practice of most Calvary Chapel pastors still today.

> Chuck Smith, Calvary Chapel Costa Mesa, and many other Calvary Chapel churches and pastors have fallen into power struggles and political disputes similar to those other Christian denominations endure.  In 2011, Smith was diagnosed with lung cancer and passed away in 2013 at age 86.

You have asked a lot of questions about the movement today, and assimilation into evangelical denominations, charismatic churches, and modern main-line churches. Because I have never been involved in this movement, I am unable to comment, other than to say I enjoy a lot of the songs that came out of Maranatha Music.

Perhaps this podcast conversation with Gino Geraci, who came to faith in Christ through the Jesus Movement and became a very early Calvary Chapel pastor, will be helpful:

https://podcast.gotquestions.org/episode-147.html

[1] https://www.gotquestions.org/Jesus-Movement.html

[2] https://www.gotquestions.org/Chuck-Smith.html

Links to other related articles which contain further information:

https://www.gotquestions.org/Calvary-Chapel.html

https://www.gotquestions.org/Vineyard-Movement.html

https://www.gotquestions.org/Jews-for-Jesus.html

Answer (score 2):

The Sovereign Lord saved me on October 9th, 1969, in the midst of the "awakening" which seemed to have occurred primarily in the '60s Counterculture. In my opinion, psychoactive drugs played a preparatory role in breaking the grip of the worldview of Materialism (philosophy) over the youth society.

The Holiness/Pentecostal/charismatic denominations capitalized upon/exploited the "awakening" due to their historic heavy emphasis upon SUBJECTIVE EXPERIENCE, in contrast to the more intellectual sectors of Christendom. The Christian metaphysical/spiritual experience and drug-induced "mind-expansion" were often compared synonymously.

Being heavily experiential, the so-labeled "Jesus Revolution" was more anti-intellectual and thus initially non-doctrinal (i.e., "Jesus-only"). Sixty-to-seventy years later, the primary benefactor has been Evangelicalism, generally speaking.

On a final note, my nearly 55-year "walk in the Spirit," together with the study of Church history, taught me to see the huge difference between religious  *"revival"* and a genuine Heaven-sent "awakening" brought about exclusively by God the Holy Spirit.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the appeal at the time was that the movement was not limited by denominational boundaries. Certainly some of the leaders and affected local churches were Anglicans, including Dennis Bennett, author of "Nine o'clock in the morning".

I can only speak anecdotally,from personal experience. Charismatic Anglicans, at any rate, were not necessarily being taken out of the Anglican church, especially when their own local ministers were supporting the movement. Therefore there was no necessity for them to be reabsorbed. I have been in two Anglican parishes where the friction between those who approved and those who disapproved was being held within the congregation. Perhaps this was because the long Anglican history of internal contention has forced the community into habits of flexibility and "agreeing to differ".